# Using Excel PERCENTILE function in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.9 and I need to use the Excel formula PERCENTILE and evaluate the formula from within Java.

The problem is that PERCENTILE is not supported.

I get a `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException:` error

I have 3 possible solutions to my problem.

1. Write my own percentile function in java and contribute it to the Apache POI library (See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html)
2. Take the relevant cells from the Excel sheet into java and calculate them using a function such as the one in [Percentile calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137391/percentile-calculation)
3. Convert the PERCENTILE into a SMALL function
   such as instead of `=PERCENTILE(A1:A10,95%)`
   then `=(SMALL(A1:A10,9)+SMALL(A1:A10,10))/2`

At this point in time I need a speedy solution. For me, the third would be the best, but it doesn't give exactly the same results.

Does anyone have any ideas before I fallback on option 2 which is a bit messy?

Comment: Why are you ruling out writing the missing function and contributing it back? That would fix your case, and fix it for everyone else too!

Comment: That was why I wrote above "at this point in time I need a speedy solution..." I did spend a couple of hours looking into writing the missing function, but realized I didn't have the resources to do it properly.

Comment: If you understand the maths/stats behind the function, it really doesn't take long to write it. [This talk from 2010](http://people.apache.org/~yegor/apachecon_us2010/Evaluation_Of_Excel_Formulas_In_POI.pptx) covers how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Gagravarr for your encouragement and also for your post [Apache POI - How to register a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298512/apache-poi-how-to-register-a-function) which was extremely helpful

I implemented the PERCENTILE function in the library in the following way:

1. I downloaded the source code for Apache POI 3.9
2. I checked for the ID number of the PERCENTILE function in src/resources/main/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/function/functionMetadata.txt ([or online](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/resources/main/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/function/functionMetadata.txt)) and it was 328
3. I thus added 
   `retval[328] = AggregateFunction.PERCENTILE;`
   to the file org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval.java
4. I added
   `public static final Function PERCENTILE = new Percentile();` to the file org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.AggregateFunction.java in the appropriate place.
5. I added to the same file the following code (which I based on the LargeSmall function; I had looked for the existing code/type of function which was most similar to what I wanted to do)

   ```
   private static final class Percentile extends Fixed2ArgFunction {

   protected Percentile() {
   }

   public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg0,
           ValueEval arg1) {
       double dn;
       try {
           ValueEval ve1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(arg1, srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
           dn = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(ve1);
       } catch (EvaluationException e1) {
           // all errors in the second arg translate to #VALUE!
           return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
       }
       if (dn < 0 || dn > 1) { // has to be percentage
           return ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR;
       }

       double result;
       try {
           double[] ds = ValueCollector.collectValues(arg0);
           int N = ds.length;
           double n = (N - 1) * dn + 1;
           if (n == 1d) {
               result = StatsLib.kthSmallest(ds, 1);
           } else if (n == N) {
               result = StatsLib.kthLargest(ds, 1);
           } else {
               int k = (int) n;
               double d = n - k;
               result = StatsLib.kthSmallest(ds, k) + d
                       * (StatsLib.kthSmallest(ds, k + 1) - StatsLib.kthSmallest(ds, k));
           }

           NumericFunction.checkValue(result);
       } catch (EvaluationException e) {
           return e.getErrorEval();
       }

       return new NumberEval(result);
   }
   ```

   }
6. I then uploaded these two files individually and could then use the PERCENTILE function normally.

Comment: If you could, please attach this new code to the [Apache POI Bugzilla Bug Tracker](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) as an enhancement with patch, so it can get included in the next release!